# Update UI and Property at same time in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have a textbox ..i want when user put any value in textbox i wan to validate the entered value on LostFocus..

Currently What is happening now my property is updated but my UI is not updated at same time..i amusing below code for that:

```
 <local:Customdatepicker x:Uid="dateValue" x:Name="dateValue"  BorderThickness="0" 
                                                            Visibility="{Binding ShowDatePicker ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                            IsEnabled="{Binding FieldValueIsEditable,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                           DateCoordinates="{Binding CoOrdinates,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                                            Text="{Binding DateFieldValue,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue=''}" 
                                                            Loaded="dateValue_Loaded" LostFocus="dateValue_LostFocus"
                                                           Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" 
                                                            Width="{Binding DatePickerWidth,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                            MouseDoubleClick="dateValue_MouseDoubleClick" 
                                                            DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDateFieldValue, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                                             >
                                    </local:Customdatepicker>
```

**I have tried below two ways**

In **first** have taken "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" but in this case my UI is not updated

```
Text="{Binding DateFieldValue,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, TargetNullValue=''}"
```

In **Second** case have taken "UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFOcus" but in this case i didn't get the updated value of textbox.
So how can i Achieve both at one time i.e the updated value in UI.

Also i have  use INotifyPropertyChanged ALready this is also not wokring.Please help me how can i solve this.

**ViewModel:**

```
 private string _datefieldvalue;
        public string DateFieldValue
        {
            get { return _datefieldvalue; }
            set
            {
                value = value == null ? string.Empty : value.Trim();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _datefieldvalue = ValidateDateValue("");
                    FirePropertyChanged();
                }
                else  if (!_datefieldvalue.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    _datefieldvalue = ValidateDateValue(value);
                    FirePropertyChanged();
                }

            }
        }

public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region PropertyChangedEventHandler   

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void FirePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `UpdateSourceTrigger` and it should properly update whenever the value changes from either the view or model since you have specified `Mode=TwoWay`

Comment: @Ephraim if o remove UpdateSourceTrigger  then suppose i have Lost focus event i wan to change textbox value at same time in UI how can i achieve that???Please read my posted issue again

Comment: @stylishCoder: as we argued yesterday the problem seems to be there. Can you tell us, what value you like to write after validation to the `Text` Property of your Picker when Focus is left? And in which case... I think it's very problematic working against the validation of the Picker. Invalid Texts are removed automatically to get `DateTime` objects as output. In my mind you try to work against this, and this won't work at all, because the control will automatically change its `Text` property to a valid `DateTime` string on lost focus.

Comment: @WPFGermany yes exactly your Point is right..actually for this i tried to preserve the value of textbox in a string property and on lost focus i assign value to textbox again but didn't work...one thing more i have taken "string" property that is binded to text of Customdatepicker..can we apply Some what any hack to update UI at same time????

Comment: By specifying the `UpdateSourceTrigger`, you are not allowing any UI update on the control unless the event is triggered. This doesn't happen when you modify the property value on your view model. See my point?

Comment: @WPFGermany also my only requirement is that if user enter value apart from date and left the textbox i wan to keep the entered value in textbox and make it required so that user must know he has entered something wrong...but i am unbabe to do so because once i left the texbox focus i don't have any updated value in property

Comment: @Ephraim ok so any solution for my problem???

Comment: Please note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` on a Binding only has an effect when there is data flow from the binding target to the source (i.e. the Binding is two-way). Here this is only the case for the Text property, so setting UpdateSourceTrigger on the Bindings of the other properties is pointless. However, at the Text Binding it only controls when the data flow from target to source is actually done. It is entirely unrelated to the data flow from source to target, so when the property is set in the view model (the source), the new value is always transferred to the control.

Comment: Post your view model code.

Comment: You could use the `DateValidationError` in the EventArgs you get the `Text`. You could use this for your message or hint to the user. The displayed `Text` will been overwritten automatically anyway (thats the behaviour from DatePicker control).

Comment: @Ephraim viewmodel code posted please check

Comment: Show your `FirePropertyChanged` code.

Comment: @Ephraim done please check

Comment: You said that when you set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` the UI did not update. It should have done so because that is the behavior of `PropertyChanged`. Also, on your `DateFieldValue` setter you are not setting the value for `_datefieldvalue`. Do you set this inside  `ValidateDateValue`? If not then it is the reason why your UI doesn't update from your view model. You should have `_datefieldvalue = value;` before `FirePropertyChanged();`

Comment: @Ephraim You seem to be constantly confusing the PropertyChanged value of the UpdateSourceTrigger property of a Binding with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. These are two different things and do not effect each other. While the `PropertyChanged` event notifies a Binding about a changed value of the source property (to make it update the target property), `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` controls that the source property is updated whenever the target property has changed (i.e. the other direction of data flow in a two-way binding).